# Issue when trying to start parcel development server

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, parceljs, npx

I am trying to use *parcel* for the first time. I installed it to my project using the `npm install parcel` command. Then I tried to start the development server by running the command `npx parcel src/index.html` and nothing happens. I do not get an error. I allowed the connection when the firewall prompt came up. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

[Result when running npx parcel command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3nZs.png)

Comment: What version of `parcel` are you using? I just tried with version `2.2.1` and worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am using v2.2.1.

Comment: I have the exakt same problem. Parcel version 1 works, not version 2, regardless of miner version. 2.0.1 doesn't work, 2.2.1 doesn't work. Perhaps a sub-dependency is the root cause? I get no errors and no output, nothing happens. Existing Parcel 2 projects work, but not new once. I will test to run npm install in working projects to see if they fail.

Answer (score 2):

According to *Devon Govett*, the creator of parcel, this issue is related to an upgrade of `napi-rs` in the `@parcel/source-map` package, which was released sometime after *Parcel 2.2.1*. For now, they have reverted this upgrade and published `@parcel/source-map v2.0.2`.

Once I read about this update, I uninstalled parcel, deleted my *.parcel-cache* folder, and reinstalled parcel. Now the `npx parcel src/index.html` command works for me.

**Sources:-**
https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7574#issuecomment-1023422239
https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7598

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the parcel in devDependencies to "latest". I did this when I had an issue using version 2.6.0 and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes. The issue was with an update parcel had released a few days before I installed parcel from npm. The issue was fixed a few weeks later. Thanks for the input David.